What justification do we have for using and trusting logic in domains that lack empirical (scientific) verification?
In the real world, we can empirically verify that our logical inferences align with reality, especially when employing deductive reasoning and classical logic. To illustrate this, consider the following examples:
Example 1: Classical Syllogism
Premises

All humans are mortal.
Socrates is a human.

Conclusion

Therefore, Socrates is mortal.

This classic syllogism follows the structure of deductive reasoning. To empirically validate this:

Empirical verification of the first premise: We observe that all humans, as recorded in scientific and historical evidence, eventually die. Mortality is a universal trait of humans.

Empirical verification of the second premise: Historical records confirm that Socrates was a human, and he shared the characteristics common to humans.

Empirical verification of the conclusion: Historical accounts show that Socrates died, confirming the conclusion that he was mortal.


Example 2: Physical Laws
Premises:

Newton’s second law:
F = ma (Force equals mass times acceleration).

Gravitational force:
F = (G * m1 * m2) / r^2
(where G is the gravitational constant, and m1, m2 are the masses of two objects, with r as the distance between them).


Conclusion (prediction):
The acceleration a of an object (like a ball) dropped near Earth's surface can be predicted by:
a = (G * M_earth) / r^2,
where M_earth is Earth’s mass and r is Earth’s radius.
Empirical verification:
We can drop an object and measure its acceleration. The experimentally observed value, approximately 9.8 m/s^2, confirms the prediction based on these physical laws.

Other widely accepted axioms of logic can also be empirically verified. For instance:
Law of Non-Contradiction:

States that a proposition cannot be both true and false at the same time.
Empirical Verification: In reality, mutually exclusive states do not coexist. For example, a door cannot be fully open and fully closed simultaneously, supporting this logical axiom.

Law of Identity:

States that every entity is identical to itself (A = A).
Empirical Verification: We observe that objects maintain consistent identities over time. A book doesn’t suddenly turn into a chair, confirming this principle.

Law of Excluded Middle:

Holds that for any proposition, either the proposition is true or its negation is true.
Empirical Verification: In classical cases, such as a light switch being either on or off, this law holds true.


In other words, we tend to take logic for granted because it consistently proves effective in real-life situations. The empirical sciences depend on logic and mathematics as tools for making predictions and inferences, given their impressive track record as reliable frameworks for modeling reality—suggesting that logic and math may be intrinsic features of how our universe operates.
However, what justification do we have for extending the use of logic to domains where empirical verification is absent—such as metaphysical claims (e.g., the existence of God or free will), mathematical abstractions (e.g., infinite sets), ethical reasoning, or even quantum mechanics, where classical logic appears to falter (see quantum logic)?
In short, if I have confidence in logic X because it empirically proves effective in domain A, what epistemological justification do I have for also applying logic X in domain B, where I lack empirical verification? Shouldn't I be in principle skeptical or at least agnostic regarding X's reliability in a domain B where empirical verification of X's reliability is lacking?

For anyone who thinks logic is untouchable, please read:

Proof that deduction is valid in all possible realities?
What justifications have been given for using particular systems of logical calculus?
Is Logic Empirical?


Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

This question starts from a reasonable premise, but has a flawed understanding of empiricism, that hampers its clarity and usefulness.
First, what is the reasonable set of assumptions.
Yes, it is an empirical question what logic applies to different parts of our world.  There are infinite different logics, and some of them are highly useful for characterizing our world, and most are not very useful.  https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/think/article/abs/guide-to-logical-pluralism-for-nonlogicians/EDFDFA1C9EB65DB71848DABD6B12D877
And yes, classical logic, which is what the OP seems to take "logic" to be, is highly useful in characterizing a lot of the world.  This provides empirical justification for using classical logic in a lot of our thinking about the world.
But empiricism is very different from what the OP assumes
The OP assumes Humean, and Logical Positivist empiricism, where empirical claims are "verified".
"Verifications" is a very poor way to do empiricism, as it is extremely subject to confirmation bias.  If one looks for "confirmations" of a principle, one can find all sorts of examples that confirm almost anything.  Generalizing from a limited number of confirmations very regularly leads one astray.  As basically all of these examples do.
Science has instead adopted Popperian refutationism.  Go looking for possible refuting test cases, not for one confirmation after another.  It is the HARD cases one must test a conjecture against, NOT pile up examples of easy cases.
Take the "law of identity".  Yes, one can find it works a lot of the time in our world.  BUT -- nothing in our world is actually identical moment to moment to moment.  The Mississippi River has a different flow rate, it's channel shifts, its drainage basin boundaries regularly move by small amounts, etc.  If one has to navigate from pier to pier along the Mississippi, if one assumes A=A, then the identical route will always be successful, or unsuccessful.  Assume A=A, program a GPS route that just worked into a robotically controlled boat and it will run aground while following that identical route.  A=/=A in that case.
Also consider the Law of the Excluded Middle.  There are multiple examples in our world that violate it. Indeterminate questions do not have an explicit true or false state.  Fore example, can God hide a truth from Itself, so even cannot know it thru Omnipotence?  By inference from we humans, who can bury memories from our awareness by segmenting our minds, a God could do so as well, so yes.  But then God could choose to de-segment its mind, and access the truth.  Then choose once more to forget it, and rehide it.  This is an indeterminate case, where both answers could be true or false.  We also have examples of incoherent statements, with no truth value, like what the density of purple.  There are also probabilistic statements, with only probabilistic truth values. All four of these categories are in the "excluded middle", and are actually the categories used in doing empiricism, not the simpler "true" or "false" categories of classical logic.
The "contradictory states are not allowed" isn't true of quantum events, where superposition of mutually excluding states is part of quantum phenomenon. The photon goes thru this slit, or that slit, or ... the superposition of both slits.
All physical "laws" are the result of symmetries, per Noether's Theorem, and every symmetry we have discovered spontaneously breaks under some circumstances.  A broken symmetry is an exception to a "law", so every one of our science laws has exceptions. https://www.pnas.org/doi/10.1073/pnas.93.25.14256
Even the "all men are mortal" point is possibly not universally true.  If the software speculation that our selfhood is identical to an algorithms is true, then the sci-fi concept of a digital upload is possible at some point in the future.  Also, biotech may eventually be able to take advantage of selective elimination of telomerase to allow our cells to replicate without aging out.
So -- by exploring hard cases, one can empirically see that every one of these examples is not actually universally true, only generally true.
However, predictive power does not require universality, only high confidence
The requirement for success in life is not perfection, only reasonable levels of reliability.
A is close enough to A over time for most logic to work.  And most of us have realized that A is not identical to A, so we need to be alert, and check for anomalies (new sandbar in the Mississippi).  We can live with logics that are mostly valid.  But need to be ready to adapt if the logical deductions fail because of an excluded middle, an A that is not an A, quantum events that superimpose contradictory states, etc.
We can make these inferences, because we have found that most of the world behaves in ways that can be characterized by logics of one kind or another.
It is this adaptability, the ability of humans to respond to failed logic cases, and toss one set of logic and try another, that is our current primary advantage over AI systems.

I will try to reason by analogy about this question, please see if this seems useful. The Question appears to be comparing two things, but either getting them backwards or putting them on the same level. We have logic, which is insubstantial, and science, which investigates material things. Intuitively, we could see that the insubstantial thing is meant to be used as a generalization or template. Templates don't fail, but objects made from them can.
My analogy question is: How can I compare the Real Number Line against my ruler to see if the Number Line is correct?.
It doesn't work that way. If we got the Real Numbers 'wrong' somehow, it would show up all over the place, while rulers probably wouldn't fail when held up against objects. We might get puzzling results though, which would cause us to stop and investigate. For example, if you have the value of PI wrong, no circle you try to make, like a large wall or something, will come out as expected. But if your ruler is incorrect, someone else's ruler may well work better than yours. Use that one.
Another example could be with Accounting. If your procedures are wrong, your accounting figures will not add up no matter what you do. If you record something wrong in your checkbook, you can compare to the bank statements, your receipts and so on. Someone has it right, for sure. But if you are calculating the GDP of a country, there are not any 'real' figures to measure against, it is inherently an approximation, like saying "10th floor" instead of "31.039 meters above the sidewalk".
So, if your map doesn't match the terrain, trust the terrain. But that doesn't invalidate the idea of maps as such. The original post question asked about extending the comparison of an insubstantial thing to checking another insubstantial thing. Well, they had darned well better agree, or one of them is simply incorrect. To figure out which, hold them both up against the world we can see and check them. Logic has held up so far. How about your field?

"So, if your map doesn't match the terrain, trust the terrain. But that doesn't invalidate the idea of maps as such." - How can you check if a map matches a terrain without testing the map empirically/scientifically? In fact,  all your examples look like experiments we can run to test if our abstractions match the empirical data. I fail to see how you are disagreeing with what I suggest in the question. On the contrary, it looks like you are agreeing.

@user80226 sure, see addition to answer. If you are saying there is no ruler to measure something with, then good luck!

"Man is the measure of all things." Perhaps it should say measurer? And: "Where wast thou when I laid the foundations of the earth? declare, if thou hast understanding. Who hath laid the measures thereof, if thou knowest? or who hath stretched the line upon it? Whereupon are the foundations thereof fastened? or who laid the corner stone thereof; When the morning stars sang together, and all the sons of God shouted for joy?" (one of my favorite parts of the Bible, along with Ecclesiastes) So, what to do with these two statements?

What I'm saying is that, if we know empirically that ruler X works in domain A, how can that be used to justify using the same ruler in domain B? It would be mere speculation to say that ruler X works in domain B as well if we don't have empirical evidence of it working in B, unless I'm missing something.

@user80226 get the empirical justification. If you can't get it, don't trust it. My sense is that no beliefs whatsoever are ever justified. If you can't kick it, or it is not biting you, it's a dream. (even then, it is still a dream)
